# Rendering D：/new/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/layout.erb(not_found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Instant rails to establish a website on which there is basic information about commodities. To achieve that,I typed the following cmds.

```
rails mebay
cd mebay
ruby script/generate model ad name:string description:text price:decimal seller_id:integer email:string img_url:string
rake db:migrate
ruby script/generate controller ads
```

then I create a file show.html.erb,later I add the code

```
map.connect '/ads/:id', :controller=>'ads', :action=>'show'
```

in the config/route.rb then I start the server,but it turns out "unknown action to show" on the webpage. And in the command appears the words in the title

Comment: and show.html.erb is in app/views/ads folder?

Comment: you have to post a full error dump that you get in development.log

Comment: I'm a rookie in this field,and I don't actually get you,could you tell me how?

Comment: well you copy pasted last line of backtrace dump into title of this question - just copypaste everything error-related from tail of log/development.log

Comment: I see..but where can I find backtrace dump?sorry to bother you ..

Comment: is this what you want?# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.

Comment: config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
        config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
config.action_view.cache_template_extensions         = false

Answer (score 0):

ok this comments discussion is much longer than i anticipated

what you pasted into title of this question is only small part of error that rails shows you in console where you started rails application

i don't know how to put it more clearly - copy paste full error dump from either console where you started rails application or from your /log/development.log file. you did copy "/new/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/layout.erb(not_found)" from somewhere didn't you?